# Div move up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning.

I'm having a doubt. Anyone know to do to move a div down or up?...

My example code. Over the div I want to pass up and 3 before the div click, then will be up 4 div. Anyone know how I can make the selection of this div

```
$(".up").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev())
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="1" >
     <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
           <div class="4">
              <div class="up">UP</div> 
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 <div class="1" >
     <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
           <div class="4">
              <div class="up">UP</div> 
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: Care to post some example HTML too? I (for some reason) feel like hitting `.prev` three times isn't the best way to traverse this. I also don't have a one-hundred-percent idea of what you're going for here, either.

Comment: @Brad : may you please translate the question too?! ;)

Comment: @Brad Christie Html add.

Comment: @user628298: So, unless I'm missing something, where do the `.prev().prev().prev()` come in? `<div class="4">` doesn't have any siblings...

Comment: @BradChristie: `<div class="4">` **is** a sibling. I believe we are trying to traverse *up* not *down*. `.prev() ===` "previous".

Comment: @Shaz: It is a _child_ of `<div class="3">`, however, it has no _siblings_ (as `.prev` would infer). I think you're confusing [`.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) with [`.parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: @BradChristie: You're right, my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".up").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".1").insertBefore($(this).parents(".1").prev(".1"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. More how do I go up to div 1 all?. Not only the up button.

Comment: @user628298: Do you want its parents parent to be included as well? Which in this case would include `<div class="3">`. If so, you can use: `$(this).closest(".3").insertBefore($(this).closest(".1"));`

Comment: How do I climb div id = "1". ?

Comment: The div is fading. not up. $(this).closest(".1").insertBefore($(this).closest(".1"));

Comment: @user628298: I'm sorry, but I don't believe I understand what you're asking here. Could you please try to explain thoroughly?

Comment: @Shaz Look at the html. Example person clicks up the div id = "1" climbs up. Thank you.

Comment: @user628298: Could you visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/575/web-developers-lounge ? Let's see if we can get what you want there.